# How to prevent a stored proc error from throwing exception in SqlClient?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

Say i have a stored proc that inserts some data into a table. If data is duplicate it will cause a sql server error (because i have unique index on some columns) and this error causes an exception in SqlClient. What can i do inside the stored proc to handle the error so no exception is being generated in my data access code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TRY CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) within your stored procedures.

This will allow you to do error handling withing SQL Server and not expose the errors to calling code.

Of course, if your `CATCH` statements cause exceptions/errors themselves they will be exposed to the client.

However, you need to ask yourself if you really do not want to know such errors - they are indications of issues in your database/codebase.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your unique index, you can tell it to silently ignore any duplicates:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_YourTable
  ON (SomeColumn) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON
```

Whether that's a good idea or not is up to you to decide. If you have such an unique index, any duplicates that you try to insert will neither cause an exception, nor will they be inserted - they just silently fail.

**Pro:** no exception

**Con:** really quite hard to debug cases where you scratch your head wondering why on earth a given row hasn't been inserted into the table, and you had no exception and no error and nothing.... (just happened to me today as a matter of fact)

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but the ideal answer here is simply not to have the sproc cause errors, but rather to validate the inserts. Or better, for the code *invoking* the sproc to only ask it to process valid data. Papering over the cracks is only going to make things uglier - it raises an exception (above a certain error-level) quite deliberately.

Comment: This is my example of when it's not true - my table has a unique constraint on one field. By nature of this field the client app will almost always insert unique values. But once in a while it will try to insert a value that already exists. So, a way to prevent it will be to check for this value in the column every time before the insert, which is not optimal. It's much easier (for implementation AND performance) to let it throw a unique constraint error and handle it gracefully, because it will be happening maybe once per 100,000 inserts

Answer (score 0):

Use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of INSERT